# User Domain level URL instead of IP address for Web Application

Tags: url, dns, webserver, mask

I have a Web application running on port 89 ( non-standard port) of a Windows 2012 R2 machine. The login page for this application needs to be accessible through a link on my website - let's call it mydomain-llc.com. I have created a button on the home page which currently explicitly provides the IP address and port number for the web server as such :

```
</head><frameset rows="100%" scrolling="yes" border="0">
<frame src="http://x.y.z.t:89/">
</frameset></html>
```

The net result is that when an user clicks the button they are taken to the login form for the web application but the IP address and port number is exposed in the browser address bar as such : http://x.y.z.t:89/

How can I mask the Ip address and have it just display a domain level URL such as :

mydomain.com/loginform.html

I understand that one way to achieve this is to setup a DNS A record at the domain manager level but would it work for an application running on a non-standard port ( port 89 in this case ) ?
Many thanks in advance for your answers.

-Yogi

Answer (score 0):

The **only** way to achieve this for internet is to setup a DNS A record (or AAAA record for IPv6).

**Yes**, it would work with any port, including 89. In that case, the address bar of browser would display something like this: `http:\\<domain_name>:89`
Please note that any port number, other than the HTTP/S standard ports (80 and 443) will also be displayed in the browser address bar.